# Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] : explain to me

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can any one explain why when I remove the bracket from the first arrow function the code start Ok but when I add the bracket again I get this error 'Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]'

code with bracket :

```
module.exports = {
    errorHandler: (fn) => {
        (req, res, next) => {
            Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
                    .catch(next)
        }
    }
}
```

code without the bracket:

```
module.exports = {
    errorHandler: (fn) => 
        (req, res, next) => {
            Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
                    .catch(next)
        }
}
```

index.js routes

```
const express = require('express');
const { postRegister } = require('../controller');
const { errorHandler } = require('../middleware')
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/register', (req, res, next) => {res.send('/register')});

router.post('/register', errorHandler(postRegister));

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

The reason the block without the brackets works is because `errorHandler()` returns a function which, express requires. The block with brackets doesn't work because `errorHandler()` isn't returning a function that matches the required [middleware function signature required by express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).

## Why is this happening?

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) evaluate the right-side of the `=>` differently if a `{` exists.

`{` Begins a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and when using a block on the right-side of an Arrow Function, a `return` is required.

If a block isn't used on the right-side of an Arrow Function, then the evaluation of the right-side is treated as an expression. The result of the expression is then returned as the result of the function.

Since the block without the brackets is treated as an expression, when `router.post('/register')` invokes `errorHandler()`, the function defined on the right-side of the `=>` is returned.

When `errorHandler()` is defined using block syntax, a `return` is required before the function that express needs. In your example with the block, no middleware function is returned by `errorHandler()`. When `router.post('/register')` invokes `errorHandler()` nothing is returned resulting in the error. If you're going to use the block syntax then you must include the `return`:

```
errorHandler: fn => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn).catch(next)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two examples upper are not the same. You should add the statement `return` into 'code with bracket'.

code with bracket:

```
module.exports = {
    errorHandler: (fn) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
                    .catch(next)
        }
    }
}
```

Another example.
`() => 2` is same as `() => { return 2 }`

Comment: A one line arrow function does not need a return statement

Comment: @DavidKabii Yes. He's saying almost what you're saying. He's saying that an arrow function with a bracket (a non-one-line-arrow-function in your terminology) needs a return function